# Django - Dynamic search result

Tags: django

I have a list of video games in my database. The user is suposed to choose their favorite games by selecting the checkbox of the wanted game.

So I have a form with the entiere list of these games. For now I use a For condition to display all the entries from my database/table.

But now I have a huge list of game that the user can choose, so I can't display everything.

Do you think It could be a good solution if I replace my system by placing a search bar which could **dynamicly** search and **add** a game.

Is there a right way to do this with Django ?
If not, could you give me the simpliest solution to solve my problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you categorize the games.And retrieve the subcategory list by ajax call to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should make use of both approaches: have a list of (ordered by) most played games which could contain a few tens of games (with the possibility to "view more" at the end of the list) for users who don't know yet what game to play and who like to discover new games. And also have a search box where users can enter the name of a game if they already know what they want to play and don't want to look it up in a list of games.

For the "view more" part of the list you should use ajax to make calls to django app without reloading the entire page and retrieve a number of games by each call. This will be more like a Single Page Application (like Twitter, for example).

Or you could use pagination and retrieve and display all games from the start and use a cache framework (and cache the query that retrieve all games) if there are performance issues.

Comment: Your idea to put the most popular games in first is quite good ;)